# Typecasting on C from string to integer

Tags: c, cs50

I'll like to convert my variable string into a integer:

Testing my code i notice I did something wrong.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string s = get_string("Name: ");
    printf("%s\n %i\n", s, (int)s);
}

output:
Name: j
j
 41127952
Name: j
j
 40714256
```

I investigate the ASCII code and the value is 106. Why keeps outputting random numbers.

Comment: Firstly, do not use `cs50.h` because it distances you from the reality of C. Secondly, get a good beginner's book. Thirdly, look into `atoi`.

Comment: ... in particular, cs50's `string` type disguises a pointer, and thereby contributes to any number of incorrect expectations about how such objects should behave.  Operating on a pointer itself is completely different from operating on the data to which it points.

Answer (score 1):

You cast the pointer to char. So it is `char *` to `int` conversion . That pointer is the place where your chars are stored. If you want to print the ASCII code of the first character you need to

```
 printf("%s\n %i\n", s, *s);
```

Comment: If he wants to convert a full string like "123" the function to use is atoi. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm

Comment: As I see in the question he was expecting the ASCII code of `j`